# PG::DependentObjectsStillExist error when trying to remove a uniqueness compound index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I was able to create a compound unique index using the following syntax:

```rb
add_index :my_table, [:col_1, :col_2], unique: true, algorithm: :concurrently, name: :my_unique_compound_index
```

However, when I try to remove that index using `remove_index` instead of `add_index`, Postgresql raises the following error:

> PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop index `my_unique_compound_index` because constraint `my_unique_compound_index` on table `my_table` requires it.
>
> HINT:  You can drop constraint `my_unique_compound_index` on table `my_table` instead.

I've tried removing the index with and without the concurrent algorithm (which I learnt about in [How to Create Postgres Indexes Concurrently in ActiveRecord Migrations](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-create-postgres-indexes-concurrently-in)) but that doesn't change the output.
I've tried removing the index inside a `change_table` block but it gives the exact same error.

Am I doing it wrong, or is their something particular to be done to force Postgresql to drop a unique compound index? Not the most helpful hint by the way :-)

Edit for additional debug information:

I'm using Rails 6.1.5 with PostgreSQL 12.9.

Here's the output when running `\d+ my_table` in `psql`:

```
Indexes:
    "my_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "my_unique_compound_index" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (col_1, col_2)
    "index_my_table_on_another_id" btree (other_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_4eb0b2d2d4" FOREIGN KEY (other_table_id) REFERENCES other_tables(id)
    "fk_rails_f7374ea9ef" FOREIGN KEY (yet_another_table_id) REFERENCES yet_another_tables(id)
Access method: heap
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving this open because the underlying problem still remains, but I was able to work around it by :

1. dropping the constraing manually in psql, using direct SQL (`ALTER TABLE my_table DROP CONSTRAINT my_unique_compound_index;`),
2. adding `if_exists: true` at the end of the `remove_index` command so that the migration doesn't throw an error now that the index is no longer there.